# How to download multiple videos in one search?

Tags: youtube-dl

I tried

```
youtube-dl 'ytsearch:football'
```

but this command downloads only the first video in the top of search results.

How to download the top 10 search result ?

Comment: Add the number of results you want at the end of the extractor, i.e. `ytsearch10`. You can also use `all` (as in `ytsearchall`) to download all search results. Ref: u/Rhomboid post in https://redd.it/3q1wfl.

Answer (score 2):

Using the option `--playlist-items ITEM_SPEC` should do what you want.

That gives you a playlist of video items to download. Specify indices of the videos in the playlist separated by commas like: `--playlist-items 1-10` to download videos 1-10 in the playlist.

That, and other options, are described [here on the youtubedl GitHub page](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#options).

Comment: ```$ youtube-dl --playlist-items 1-10 'ytsearch:football'
[youtube:search] query "football": Downloading page 1
[download] Downloading playlist: football
[youtube:search] playlist football: Collected 1 video ids (downloading 1 of them)
[download] Downloading video 1 of 1
[youtube] RAQQX36j_A0: Downloading webpage
[youtube] RAQQX36j_A0: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] RAQQX36j_A0: Extracting video information
WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.
```

Comment: This does not work with ytsearch. Solution: Append a number to `ytsearch` such as `ytsearch10`